# Dlib was compiled to use SSE41 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine

Tags: python

Установил на свой сервер (Ubuntu) Dlib для Python, используя этот [гайд](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/01/22/install-dlib-easy-complete-guide/). Получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Dlib was compiled to use SSE41 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
```

[image: Dlib was compiled to use SSE41 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.]

Возможно ли исправить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему, может быть кому-нибудь пригодится:

1) Скачиваем dlib через git:

```
 git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
```

2) В dlib/tools/python редактируем файл CMakeLists.txt:

Меняем эту строчку:

```
set(USE_SSE4_INSTRUCTIONS ON CACHE BOOL "Use SSE4 instructions")
```

На эту:

```
set(USE_SSE2_INSTRUCTIONS ON CACHE BOOL "Use SSE2 instructions")
```

3) В папке dlib выполняем команду для установки:

```
 python3 setup.py install --yes USE_NEON_INSTRUCTIONS
```